# PySpark: Use dataframe column as index for python list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe. It has an integer column "index" and a double column "feature". I also have a python list `parameter`with length the same as number of unique elements in "index" column.

I would like to generate a new column in the following way in PySpark: for each row, if the value of "index" is `i`, then I would like to multiply "feature" by `parameter[i]` for this new column.

For small number of elements in `parameter`, I can use `when().when().otherwise` to generate the output. How should I do it when the number of elements in `parameter` is large?

Comment: What is your spark version?

Comment: the spark version is 2.4